# How can I have Solr import all text in a file that contains embedded special chars (namely "<" char)?

Tags: solr

I am trying to import text data into an XML file (sample below) for import into Solr. Everything is working with the exception of any text that has "<" char's. I have tried using < to escape those, but still it returns an error "Unexpected char '@' whenever text on the same line contains the XML open tag char "<".  Solr message indicates that it is expecting a space, or '>' or "/>".

I am generating the XML files and can do whatever pre-parsing is needed. But at this point I'm not really sure what can be done short of simply removing them as they are processed. From what I've read in Solr books, it seems that the StandardTokenizerFactory would handle this type of information as it is very common in emails. I thought that factory would handle that as well as URLs. Yet, Solr also returned a namespace error for http://www.test.com. But this too is apparently for also associated with the presence of the "<" char.

Am I missing something simple somewhere? These seem like standard character patterns that should not generate errors. Hoping someone has an idea on where I am confusing Solr. If I take out these few characters, the indexing works fine. But with hundreds of files, I need a robust solution, even if it means dropping characters. However, that would hopefully not be a last resort as I would like to retain as much info for indexing as possible.

Thanks for any light that can be shed on this issue!

```
<update>
<add>
        <doc>
                <field name="id">001</field>
                <field name="text_en"> Sample info
                     John Smith <j.smithcha@abc.com>
                     additional info here...
                </field>
        </doc>
        <doc>
                <field name="id">002</field>
                <field name="text_en"> Some special <(*&!^ characters/> here  </field>
        </doc>
</add>
</update>
```

Comment: Since you're dealing with XML (without CDATA) you probably need, at least, to escape [these characters](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/bc4j/developing_bc_projects/obcCustomXml.htm). `<` becomes `&lt;` and so on. Have you tried this?

Comment: That seems like it would not be escaping, but more of a URL encoding. If I used that, would they be converted back for query operations, i.e. how would the query find "<" char?) What would be great is if there was a control to ignore all tags/data (basically treat all as text data) between the <field> and </field> tags. There should not be any reason that Solr should treat it otherwise. I'm thinking of just pre-parsing to strip out the offending character. Unfortunately there is some text that have mathematical comparisons and uses < and > characters, so I may have to sacrifice that data.

Comment: Thing is, you're dealing with XML data and `<field><...</field>` is not valid XML afaik. Solr does have filters (you can define them at index time for example to deal with whatever scenarios) but, without further information, it would seem you're dealing with a simple XML not valid error.

Comment: I see what you mean and understand what needs to be done now. With that in mind I have a couple options, but main thing is as you pointed out is first escaping/converting those special characters to the correct format (e.g. %lt;) to render the XML correct. This is the correct answer. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer as provided by nitrin0 is to ensure that the XML data is well-formed and valid by escaping the character "<" to "<" as well as other characters that would be incorrectly interpreted by an XML parser.

The character translation should be as shown below (in following with the XML standard):

```
<    &lt;   (less than symbol)
>    &gt;   (greater than symbol)
&    &amp;  (ampersand symbol) 
'    &apos;     (apostrophe symbol)
"    &quot; (quotation mark symbol)
```

Also, one may consider using CDATA to ensure that the XML data is correctly processed.

Tx to nitrin0 for finding the solution!